# How to use PostgreSQL's "INSERT...ON CONFLICT" (UPSERT) feature with flask_sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The PostgreSQL `ON CONFLICT` clause in `INSERT` statements provides "upsert" functionality (i.e. update an existing record, or insert a new one if no such record exists).  This functionality is supported in SQLAlchemy via the `on_conflict_do_nothing` and `on_conflict_do_update` methods on the PostgreSQL dialect's `Insert` object (as described [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert)):

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

insert_stmt = insert(my_table).values(
    id='some_existing_id',
    data='inserted value'
)

do_nothing_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_nothing(
    index_elements=['id']
)

conn.execute(do_nothing_stmt)

do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
    constraint='pk_my_table',
    set_=dict(data='updated value')
)

conn.execute(do_update_stmt)
```

I am using `flask_sqlalchemy`, which manages SQLAlchemy's engine, session, and connections for you.  To add an element to the database, I create an instance of my model, add it to the database session, and then call commit, something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class MyTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String)

relation = MyTable(id=1, data='foo')
db.session.add(relation)
db.session.commit()
```

So the `Insert` object is completely wrapped and obscured by `flask_sqlalchemy`.

How can I access the PostgreSQL-specific dialect methods to perform an upsert?  Do I need to bypass `flask_sqlalchemy` and create my own session?  If I do this, how can I ensure no conflicts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It turns out you can execute a lower-level statement on the `db.session`.  So a solution looks something like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert as pg_insert

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class MyTable(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, _id, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = _id
        self.data = kwargs['data']

    def as_dict(self):
        return {'id': self.id, 'data': self.data}

    def props_dict(self):
        d = self.as_dict()
        d.pop('id')
        return d

relation = MyTable(id=1, data='foo')
statement = pg_insert(MyTable)\.
    values(**relation.as_dict()).\
    on_conflict_do_update(constraint='id',
                          set_=relation.props_dict())

db.session.execute(statement)
db.session.commit()
```

The `as_dict()` and `props_dict()` methods in my model class allow me to use the constructor to filter out unwanted properties from the incoming HTTP request.

Comment: This fails for me with the error that `constraint "id" for table "foobar" does not exist`, even though `id` is created as a `db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)` field.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Worked well for my need to run on_conflict_do_nothing() with some small changes to your code example.

Comment: @deed02392 I'm having the same error, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @avocado, I must have done in the end, but I guess it was something obvious hence I didn't update here again. We can have a chat if you can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using compilation extension (https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/compiler.html):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import Insert

@compiles(Insert)
def compile_upsert(insert_stmt, compiler, **kwargs):
    """
    converts every SQL insert to an upsert  i.e;
    INSERT INTO test (foo, bar) VALUES (1, 'a')
    becomes:
    INSERT INTO test (foo, bar) VALUES (1, 'a') ON CONFLICT(foo) DO UPDATE SET (bar = EXCLUDED.bar)
    (assuming foo is a primary key)
    :param insert_stmt: Original insert statement
    :param compiler: SQL Compiler
    :param kwargs: optional arguments
    :return: upsert statement
    """
    pk = insert_stmt.table.primary_key
    insert = compiler.visit_insert(insert_stmt, **kwargs)
    ondup = f'ON CONFLICT ({",".join(c.name for c in pk)}) DO UPDATE SET'
    updates = ', '.join(f"{c.name}=EXCLUDED.{c.name}" for c in insert_stmt.table.columns)
    upsert = ' '.join((insert, ondup, updates))
    return upsert
```

This should ensure that all insert statements behave as upserts.